# how to call a simple javascript method in cefsharp resource handler -OnBeforeResourceLoad-

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

This is where I want to block some content to be displayed when the page is loaded.

This is the function simply returns true or false

```
   _myfilters.blocking.matches('" + request.Url + "', '" + elType + "',  document.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, ''));
```

I want to decide CefReturnValue according to this javascript method above.

How can I do it?

```
    CefReturnValue IRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
bool result = ... this is coming from javascript, how ?

if (result ) 
CefReturnValue.Cancel;
else
CefReturnValue.Continue;

}
```

//My approach

```
   CefReturnValue IRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {



        string elType = "object";


        CefReturnValue cc = CefReturnValue.Continue;


        //  Task<CefSharp.JavascriptResponse> response = BrowserView.browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(" function() { return _myfilters.blocking.matches('" + request.Url + "', '" + elType + "',  document.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '')); } ");
        Task<CefSharp.JavascriptResponse> response = BrowserView.browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("onBeforeRequestHandler({type:'" + elType + "' , url:'" + request.Url + "' , frameDomain:document.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '')});");
        Func<Task<CefSharp.JavascriptResponse>> func = () =>
            {

                response.Wait();
                return response;
            };

        func.BeginInvoke((ar) =>
        {
            var result = func.EndInvoke(ar);
            if (result.Result.Result != null && bool.Parse(result.Result.Result.ToString()))
            {
                cc = CefReturnValue.Cancel;
            }
        },
        null);

        return cc;
    }
```

Comment: I'd advise against that. If you can get a copy of `_myfilters.blocking` when the initial page loads and execute the regex in `C#` that would be my advice.

Comment: @amaitland please see my new edit.. I got response now but I think I am late to cancel what I wanted to cancel according to js function. Please help me

Comment: You would need to use the callback, return `ContinueAsync`.